# What can we say about the integral $\int_{\Omega}(f\circ\frac{du}{dt})dt$ in some given conditions on the functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a convex function and $u:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$ such that $u|_{\partial \Omega}=0$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R.$ Then can we say anything about the integral $\int_{\Omega}(f\circ\frac{du}{dt})dt$  ?**

Actually, I need this integral as $0$. Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If $f$ is positive it will not be $0$, for example.

Comment: @nicomezi yes, I got it. Thanks